# Calculating cyclotron orbits in a lattice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics

I have a naive question, is it possible to obtain the wavepacket dynamics that give rise to cyclotron orbits from a real space tight-binding Hamiltonian?
Consider a square lattice in the presence of a constant magnetic field that amounts to say that the hopping elements acquire a phase. Let $H = \sum_{<m,n>} H_{m,n}$ be the real space tight-binding Hamiltonian describing such a system.

The cyclotron orbits are actually the semi-classical approximation to the above dynamics that $ H$ captures. These orbits are the paths of the electron $\dot{\textbf{r}}(t) = \partial H/\partial \textbf{p}$. How can we obtain this information from the above $H$?

**Numerically:**
We can diagonalize $H$, to obtain eigenfunctions $\psi_{m,n}$ from this, we can obtain probability densities $|\psi_{m,n}|^{2}$.
To obtain wavepacket dynamics $\Psi(t)$ , we solve Schrodinger's equation: $i\partial\Psi(t) = H \Psi$. This equation can be solved for some initial conditions. The solution tells if we make an excitation in the system at a site $(m_0,n_0)$ (initial condition) then how it will propagate in the lattice. [This was my attempt, link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251240/plotting-of-probability-density-on-a-lattice-and-studying-dynamics).
However, this does not give any information about the semi-classical information!

Comment: The state with sufficiently large angular momentum is correlated with the classical orbital movement.

Comment: @AlexTrounev That's right. Does it mean if we consider a state with high angular momentum it will mimic the semi-classical motion? For that, can we try some Gaussian wavepacket? I have no idea how to excite a Gaussian wave in Mathematica. I saw your beautiful solution to my question.

Comment: Are lattice coordinates correspond to space coordinates?

Comment: @AlexTrounev not actually, i think it’s crucial for Gaussian wavepacket?

Comment: What is the physical meaning of this lattice?

Comment: @AlexTrounev my bad, you can say that it is a space coordinate

Answer (score 2):

The state with sufficiently large angular momentum is correlated with the classical orbital movement. The question is how we can prepare this state? If we use Hamiltonian described on [this page](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/251240/plotting-of-probability-density-on-a-lattice-and-studying-dynamics) and plot all eigenvectors, then we have picture
[image: Figure 1]
States from 3 to 10 looks promising, and if we prepare initial state from some mixture of  its, then animated peripheral region of lattice looks as follows

[image: Figure 2]

It looks like rotation with period of $T=37$. I think that for the large lattice we can get something similar to cyclotron orbit.
**Update 1**. Eigenvalues of Hamiltonian described above are

```
{2.90519, -2.90519, -2.76278, -2.76278, 2.76278, 2.76278, -2.58201, \
2.58201, -2.58201, 2.58201, 2.52133, -2.52133, -2.39276, 2.39276, \
-2.34139, 2.34139, 2.25356, 2.25356, -2.25356, -2.25356, 2.13097, \
2.13097, -2.13097, -2.13097, -1.95441, 1.95441, -1.95441, 1.95441, \
-1.92521, 1.92521, -1.86377, 1.86377, -1.86377, 1.86377, -1.69775, \
1.69775, -1.61748, 1.61748, -1.58945, 1.58945, -1.58945, 1.58945, \
-1.58691, 1.58691, 1.57744, -1.57744, -1.36333, -1.36333, 1.36333, \
1.36333, 1.29892, -1.29892, -1.29892, 1.29892, 1.27992, -1.27992, \
-1.27992, 1.27992, -1.25195, 1.25195, 1.07599, -1.07599, 1.06731, \
1.06731, -1.06731, -1.06731, 1.04507, -1.04507, -1.04507, 1.04507, \
-1., 1., -1., -1., 1., 1., -0.863067, 0.863067, -0.839226, 0.839226, \
-0.74239, 0.74239, 0.74239, -0.74239, -0.692981, 0.692981, -0.491724, \
-0.491724, 0.491724, 0.491724, -0.35947, 0.35947, -0.229448, \
-0.229448, 0.229448, 0.229448}
```

We can combine eigenvectors with negative sign of eigenvalues, for example, `{2, 3, 4, 7, 9}` as initial condition. Then we have picture with illusive rotation
[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Alex! Your solution goes to the point. However, if we have to decide the higher angular momentum states, I would think to look for figures where probability amplitudes is mostly localized at the boundary. Like 31-36, someothers. Isn't it?

Comment: Also, I was working for the bigger lattices, is there a way to speed up the code? It looks `Manipulate` is terribly slow for this case.

Comment: There are many possibilities to get rotation including random combination of all states. What size of lattice do you run?

Comment: For me, it can go upto 2000 lattice sites.